# LED with built-in resistor and voltage drop

Tags: led, resistors, 12v

I accidentally bought 12 V LEDs, so an LED with a built-in resistor (you can see it as a black dot on the anode).
Now I measured the voltage and get after the LED still a voltage of 11.3 V, when the LED is supplied with 12.5 V from a power supply.

I find this strange, because usually the resistor will drop the voltage so far that the LED gets its 1.7 - 2.0 V. So after the LED should be only 1.7 V or am I wrong?

Where is my thinking error or are the LEDs with series resistor internally connected in parallel?

Shouldn't that be the same circuits, just one had the resistor inside the LED and the other one has the resistor before the LED?

Edit: Of course I'm measuring this way, I'm sorry

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  When you say, "Now I measured the voltage and get after the LED still a voltage of 11.3V" what EXACTLY does that mean?  Please include a schematic drawing.

Comment: The scheme is pretty easy: 12V+ -> Measure Clamp 1 -> LED with built-in resistor -> Measure Clamp 2 -> GND

Comment: That sounds like you are measuring the voltage across the LED's pins? That should be whatever you feed it with. If not, you'd have a short circuit and magic blue smoke escaping from it...

Comment: Resistor is internal, you can not measure drop voltage of LED.

Comment: I added the circuit. How should I measure the voltage instead in your opinion?

Comment: Instead of what? You do not have access to LED, so youmeasuring supplied voltage. And it is lower because your PS is not stabilized. Under load internal voltage drop.

Comment: Edited the image because I noticed it's wrong. Otherwise I measure of course the voltage of the ps

Comment: In your most recent update you show that your voltmeter is connected across a wire. You'll get a 0 V reading for that.

Comment: Which wire do you mean?

Comment: Look at VM1 and VM3. Both meter probes are connected to the same wire between D1 and V1-. You've effectively connected the probes together and the meter would read 0 V.

Comment: The photo seems to have the voltage meter in series with LED. As extremely small current flows, there is an extremely low voltage drop over LED component and therefore almost all of the drop will be over the multimeter.

Comment: Looking at the circuit you're measuring from negative to negative. That should yield a 0V reading.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasWeller if you really measure what you have drawn you have always 0V (since your multimeter is basically measuring the same point). Probably you are measuring something else.

Comment: This schematic can't be correct. If you did have things wired up like that, you'd be measuring 0 volts no matter what.

Answer (score 6):

Your battery, LED and voltmeter are all in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvTZiw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. You're not measuring the voltage "after" (or "before") the LED. You are measuring the voltage across the LED-resistor combination.*

In this circuit it is the same as measuring the supply voltage.

To measure the LED voltage you would need to do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpUnhH.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. To measure the LED voltage in your 12 V LED would require some delicate surgery.*

> Now I measured the voltage and get after the LED still a voltage of 11.3V, when the LED is supplied with 12.5V from a power supply.

That means that your 12 V supply is drooping. To confirm this connect your voltmeter to the battery and monitor while you switch the LED on and off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsufb1.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Measuring the voltage **in series** with the LED gives no useful information.*

In this situation the voltmeter presents a series resistance of (typically) 10 MΩ in series with the 1.2 kΩ of the LED. Since the meter's resistance is 10,000 times that of the LED resistor almost all the voltage is dropped across it rather than the LED.

If you wish to do something useful then switch your meter to mA and use Figure 3 to measure the current through the LED. **Remember to switch back to V when finished.** If you forget and connect it up as shown in Figure 1 you will pass a high current through the meter and blow the fuse if it has one and blow the meter if it hasn't.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course your right and I'm measuring with your method...

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I understand now. So I can measure the amperage and then calculate with this.

Comment: Yes. You'll then know the current, you will have to estimate the LED voltage drop (typically 2 to 2.2 V for green) and then you can work out the internal resistor value. You might find what I've written on [LEDnique.com](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/) useful.

Comment: Thank you. But why is the voltmeter showing this 11.3V if it's connected in series (e.g. my picture in first post from my bench). Should it not show like 0V because of the internal resistor?

Comment: More likely it's the forward voltage drop of the LED at the extremely low current you are drawing through it. Look at the IV curves in the previous link. The valve illustrations in [What is an LED](http://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/) may be helpful too.

Comment: @0x30 You were measuring under conditions where the LED wasn't lit. With the LED not lit, the current flow is nearly zero and the voltage drop of the resistor is near zero. The reading reflects what's happening under conditions that don't relate to what happens when there's lots of current flowing through the LED.

Answer (score 2):

On picture voltmeter connected in series with LED and internal resistance. Voltmeter input resistance is high, usually around 1 Mohm. So you restricted LED current and diode drop voltage smaller then normal. Voltmeter shows drop voltage on itself. So the rest voltage 12.6-11.24=1.34V is drop voltage on diode and internal resistor.

Comment: It is "ohm" (not "Ohm"). See e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm. You can [edit your answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/559584/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).